# Anyone else feels the show notes spoil the podcast?

Tags: feature-request, podcast

The show notes are posted as soon as the podcast comes out, but if I read them I have no need to listen to it because they are so detailed.

Can we get a smaller summary of the topics and maybe give us a little time to listen to it and post the full show notes at a later time?

I work around it by not reading them prior to listening to the podcast, but I'd also like to know the topics in advance...

Comment: Your complaint is that they are being *too* informative?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it can ruin it if you read it ahead of time. I usually don't refer to the show notes until after I've listened to the podcast.

Answer (score 23):

I think having very detailed show notes is incredibly helpful, especially if you're ever trying to reference back to a previous podcast (which certainly happens here on meta). If you feel they spoil the show, then I wouldn't read them or would figure out how to skim them so they don't spoil what is to come. Personally, I choose not to read them.

Answer (score 15):

It's two guys (sometimes with guest) talking about programming.  What's there to spoil?  It's not like you're going to download next week's podcast and find out Joel is Jeff's father or something.

Comment: ... *OR WILL YOU?*

Comment: Well... that actually happened in star wars... so...

Comment: thanks a lot, juan. i've never seen star wars and i was going to watch them this weekend.  (that's sarcasm.)

Comment: At least you did not spoil him Titanic. Man, who would have thought that the unsinkable ship can indeed sink?

Answer (score 11):

I think it's the other way around.

I usually skim the content. If looks interesting enough I hear the podcast.

If it doesn't look that relevant nor I don't have the time I skip it.

Eventually I may just read the content or do both.

Comment: Same here, except the show notes tell me whether or not I need to listen to the podcast *right now* or if it can wait for tomorrow.

Comment: @Kyle: xactly!!!

Answer (score 8):

Why not use the [ITConversations feed](http://rss.conversationsnetwork.org/series/stackoverflow.xml) for the show? The show notes don't show up in that one, but the MP3 does.

(I use both feeds; one for the spoiler-free MP3 acquisition, the other for notes after I've listened to the show ;)

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I don't understand your logic. If by reading a summary of it, it is *spoiled*, then you really have no interest in the actual podcast and shouldn't consider listening to it in the first place -- doing so would clearly be a waste of time in your regards. Read the show notes and move on. If on the other hand, you read the show notes and are intrigued, then listen to the podcast. I don't see a valid reason why this should be changed.

It's a matter of personal choice, do what you feel is best. This isn't the next installment of Harry Potter, and people aren't standing outside with megaphones yelling "Dumbledore dies!". You're allowed to do whatever you want with your time, so exercise this right.

Answer (score 3):

If there were no show notes I would never know what was being talked about because I have only listened to a single podcast out of the sixty some that have been posted.