# Podcast #66 - Discussion Ideas. (Unofficial)

Tags: discussion, podcast

Well we got [Jon's question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11030/podcast-64-discussion-ideas-unofficial/11040#11040) answered on podcast 65. So +1 for us (and Jon)

---

What would you like to see discussed on Podcast #66?

Please post only one topic per user and look down the list and vote up things you'd like to see. You can be as detailed as you wish.

---

The [previous podcast discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12785/podcast-65-discussion-ideas-unofficial) is there to <s>steal</s> revise past ideas.

---

[Podcast #66](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/podcast-66/)   [Transcript wiki](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W29078)

[<= previous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12785/podcast-65-discussion-ideas-unofficial)   [next =>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19915/podcast-67-discussion-ideas-unofficial)

Comment: Whoops sorry, forgot CW :(

Comment: LINK TO THE LAST ONE, MAN

Answer (score 68):

Either on this podcast or perhaps on the one after Sept 1, but how about an interview with the FogCreek dev working on StackExchange.

I'd be interesting in

- What are some of the challenges working on the SO codebase, and making that codebase into an easy to administer (for general users) platform
- His perspective on the MVC framework and other technology's involved, would he have done anything different?
- How StackExchange and the StackOverflow team are merging the ongoing updates
- What he'd (personally) like to see in the SO engine in the future
- [sarcasm] What it's really like to work for Joel (and is Jeff's code any good) [/sarcasm]

Comment: I've actually heard that the code is very good. Haven't seen any though.

Comment: @Olafur, I meant that point as a bit sarcastic, I have edited to include the appropriate sarcasm tags

Comment: our code is really bad IMO.

Comment: +1 for this - I'd like in particular to hear about the policies and allowed or expected uses of stackexchange
In fact anything about stackexchange would be good - there's not a lot of discussion about it (from the people who know that is - not the idle speculation of the rest of us in meta) anywhere

Comment: you guys haven't figured out who the SE dev is? I mentioned on the podcast that he was a 10k+ rep SO user, along with his first name. That's all the hints I'm giving. :)

Comment: Dev is http://stackoverflow.com/users/2603/aaron-maenpaa, at the time that I posted I didn't feel like going through the posts to find it, but since you threw down the gauntlet

Comment: Jeff's being humble.  The code is very code.

Comment: @Michael, the code is very code? ;-)

Comment: Oops.  The code is very good!

Comment: Another question for Aaron: when will September 1rst actually be this year?

Answer (score 62):

It sounds like Joel's going to be away, so *potentially* the next podcast could be quite a while away.

However, I don't see why Jeff shouldn't record a podcast with a guest instead of Joel... even if they only manage a half hour show instead of the full hour, I'm sure it would still be well worth listening too.

And yes, I'd love to go on the podcast some time... unless the mysterious "lost" email was because Jeff and Joel decided they couldn't stand the sound of my voice ;) There are plenty of other more interesting people though...

Comment: I would have posted an url to the recording in a comment to your question. That way you don't have to worry about it getting lost in the email.

Comment: @Brad: I didn't expect it to get lost though - it's email, which isn't exactly unreliable these days. Next time though :)

Comment: I find it hard to believe there are more interesting people than Jon Skeet.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that people are so infatuated with Jon. (no offense Jon)

Comment: Looks like it's going to be 2 weeks.
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/yet-another-reason-to-dislike-france/

Comment: @jjnguy: You think *you* find it hard to believe. Imagine how *I* feel, from the perspective of knowing how ordinary I am. Things may change after the London DevDay.

Comment: Great idea ... nice of Jon to offer.  But one thing I'd definitely like to hear is Jon's opinion on everybody's infatuation with him.  It's got to be wierd.  Has he had any stalkers yet?

Answer (score 49):

I would like to hear how Jeff (and his team) Get Things Done! He just seems to wear so many hats, do so many things, developing, sysadmin, blogger, moderating the sites, avid twitter, plus he seems to be reading a million blogs, podcasts, youtube videos a day!

And on top of that has a baby!

I would like to know how he plans his day and deals with all these different tasks.

Comment: recommendation: do not have a baby.

Comment: @Jeff, As our sons were born a couple of hours apart, I to would like to hear how you getting all this done.

Comment: Yeah, I find myself thinking "What would Jeff Atwood be doing?" whenever I find a free moment.  And when I read though his twitter feed I think "Well, I guess he would be twittering!"  But seriously, how many hours a day does Jeff "work"?  How much is spent on thinking about what to code, coding, twittering, blogging, podcasting, twittering, etc?

Comment: Are weekends strict family time?

Comment: Sorry for the derail, but I want to make sure not to make this mistake, could you tell me How is babby formed?????

Comment: @Brian I'm sure there is a Forking Process joke here somewhere...

Answer (score 46):

Since you rag on PHP [every](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W29076) [freakin](http://twitter.com/codinghorror/statuses/3277610210) [week](http://twitter.com/codinghorror/statuses/3527327800), why not invite a PHP enthusiast, like:

- Andrei Zmievski, PHP contributor, former Digg employee [twitter](http://twitter.com/a)
- Matthew Weier O'Phinney, Project Lead for the Zend Framework, Zend Corp employee [twitter](http://twitter.com/weierophinney) [blog](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/)
- Rasmus Lerdorf, PHP contributor
- Anyone listed here: http://www.php.net/credits.php

I think a dialog would be much more interesting than the typical one sided rants.

Comment: I like the idea of something about PHP too . . . get a different opinion in there and maybe change the way we think.  I happen to like PHP but I like C# too (and even VBScript . . . they all have a place in my heart!).

Comment: I heart this idea so much I would upvote it ten times if I could.

Comment: Pish, a PHP fan would say that!

Comment: I don't know if the sounds of a barfight would work all that well on a podcast. Maybe video it?

Answer (score 43):

Interview [David Smalley](https://twitter.com/davidsmalley) and/or [Paul Farnell](https://twitter.com/unsalted) from:

[image]
<sub>(source: [doctype.com](http://assets0.doctype.com/images/logo-large.png?2))</sub>

Comment: You have an upvote from me in spirit - I have to wait a few hours before I can actually upvote though.

Answer (score 18):

Have Jon Skeet sit in for Joel.

Answer (score 16):

Future plans of the League of Justice. Also, any world domination-related activities that they may contain.

Comment: And what websites would be in the League of Injustice?

Comment: the hyphen site

Comment: @jakemcgraw: isn't that an arch enemy?

Answer (score 15):

I would like to see Jeff get together all the Stack Overflow Associates to talk about what it is like for in the past year and now having 4 sites running the same code.

Answer (score 13):

Jeff's other significant half, I'm sure she would have some great stories to tell!

Comment: Scott Hanselman did that once. It was a decent show.

Comment: Come on, give the guy some privacy. He has a family, that's about as much as we should know.

Answer (score 11):

Invite your mother for a 10 minute chat, Jeff.  *What is it I do again, Mom?*

Answer (score 9):

After reading [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18097/non-visual-way-to-see-if-a-question-you-asked-has-an-accepted-answer) post and realising that we actually have a <kbd>blind-programmer</kbd> tag and two [confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370976/what-are-some-good-computer-science-resources-for-a-blind-programmer) blind users on StackOverflow, one with [6000+](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14744/jared) reputation already, I would like to know how and what has been done to make the site more accessible for these users, and although a minority how Jeff and Joel feel about reaching such a unique target?

I would also like to hear their input on the [What are some good computer science resources for a Blind Programmer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370976/what-are-some-good-computer-science-resources-for-a-blind-programmer) (Question 370976) question on StackOverflow.

Comment: I like this idea, note Scott Hanselman did an interview with Saqib Shaikh who is a blind developer (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanselminutesPodcast125AccessibilityInWebAndRichApplications.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

I want to hear Jeff go mano-a-mano with Zed Shaw http://zedshaw.com

Answer (score 6):

Simialr to @Jonathan Sampson's post, I'd like to hear from The How To Geek as well as David Smalley and/or Paul Farnell in the same podcast.

- Why did they join the league of justice
- What has unexpected things have happened since they were announced
- What are they going to do to better integrate with the other SO sites
- Are they anticipating moving over to the StackExchange Engine (why/why not) 
  ...

Comment: I still don't get that site's belonging in the SO group. Doctype on the other hand makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Ctrl Alt... Think of as SuperUser for people who are even less informed

Comment: @Rob Allen I think most of those people are actually across the divide and have trouble starting the computer.

Answer (score 6):

Interview Phil Haack and/or Scott Hanselman. I know that you've done lots of podcasts with Hanselman but I don't recall any with Phil Haack. Also Rob Conery worked on ASP.NET MVC and I know that he's no longer with Microsoft but his angle on what you've done with MVC would also be interesting.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to know whether Joel is indeed [Jeff's father](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14126/anyone-else-feels-the-show-notes-spoil-the-podcast/14133#14133).  :)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe Jeff can chat to Seth Godin on the phone? I mean, I always like hearing stuff about marketing and the software business that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Call in Show! Call in to Jeff Atwood with your questions (via Skype) about Stack Overflow.

Comment: You should always eat your own dog food. So using SO to get good questions on the show (voted by the users of SO) seems like a good idea.

Comment: You voted me down sir. </sadpanda>.

Comment: Yes sir.              :(

Answer (score 3):

Anders Hejlsberg to talk about .............. DELPHI (woot^^)

Answer (score 3):

This may surprise you, it doesn't matter who's in the podcast, where it's made, what it's about, **so long as it is made at regularly scheduled intervals**. Granted it's polite to start a less ordinary podcast with a comment that says, "this week Joel is in france, so we have a ventriloquist with a dummy of Joel as a guest".

Make a podcast. Un ordinary ones may be short. They may even be a edited version of out-takes. Anything....

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to hear a discussion about the good and the bad points of operating Stack Overflow with remote developers.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to hear a discussion with a developer that is working on the AdSense for Google. Jeff has voiced a lot of opinions about AdSense which I tend to agree with but hearing from the source about why their model isn't working as intended and what they are planning to do about it would be very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Alex Papadimoulis from TheDailyWTF was an awesome guest, I certainly wouldn't mind hearing an encore.

Answer (score 1):

How about how you obtain the detailed metrics and statistics for StackOverflow. Did you have to code the logging of key metrics? Also, how does Stack Overflow make enough money from just the few ads to pay for Jeff and the other two developers, plus other expenses like hosting, etc? BTW, where is is hosted?
Brian

Comment: There's a banner/link in the footer of each page for the host. Currently it's Peak Internet.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to hear some talk on the Maker's Schedule/Manager's Schedule as Paul Graham talks about [here](http://www.paulgraham.com/makersschedule.html) and how this may effect work on the sites as well as how Fog Creek handles this type of thing. This seems to be something that people I work with don't get who are outside of the programmer group despite it being a big part in how things get done.

Answer (score 0):

Let Jeff explain for all us culturally challenged what all those references to ponies mean.

Comment: It's all TheTXI's fault.