# Non visual way to see if a question you asked has an accepted answer?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, accessibility

I currently have no way to tell what questions I've asked have accepted answers.

After the vote up and vote down graphics my screen reader announces "graphic check". I know clicking on this graphic will allow me to accept an answer since my reputation increases by two the first time I do it on a specific question.

If I go back to look at a question, there’s no way to tell if I’ve already accepted an answer though. Would it be possible to provide some non visual way of showing weather a question had an accepted answer such as alt tags on the “check” image that announce whether the image is to select an answer as accepted, or whether you're actually looking at the answer you’ve already accepted?

I may be way off base here since I can’t actually see how the screen is laid out but hopefully this makes sense to someone.

**Update**

When I look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118643/is-there-a-way-to-convert-indentation-in-python-code-to-braces) with my screen reader the following is the element information my screen reader gives me when I ask for detail while on the "check" graphic. Based on this I setting either the alt attribute or title should work, although alt attribute would work by default while my screen reader would have to be told to use the title attribute instead of the alt attribute for stackoverflow.com and associated sites.

```
Element Information:

Tag IMG has 7 parameters:
alt=check
class=vote-accepted
height=31
id=vote-accepted-118744
src=http://sstatic.net/so/img/vote-accepted.png
title=Click to set this answer as your accepted answer; click again to toggle.
width=30
MSAA Role=28

Tag DIV has 1 parameters:
class=vote
MSAA Role=424

Tag TD has 1 parameters:
class=votecell
MSAA Role=1D

Tag TR has 0 parameters:

Tag TBODY has 0 parameters:
MSAA Role=429

Tag TABLE has 0 parameters:
MSAA Role=18

Tag DIV has 2 parameters:
class=answer 
id=answer-118744
MSAA Role=424

Tag DIV has 1 parameters:
id=answers
MSAA Role=424

Tag DIV has 1 parameters:
id=mainbar
MSAA Role=424

Tag DIV has 1 parameters:
id=content
MSAA Role=424

Tag DIV has 1 parameters:
class=container
MSAA Role=424

Tag BODY has 0 parameters:

Tag HTML has 0 parameters:

Tag #document has 1 parameters:
href=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118643/is-there-a-way-to-convert-indentation-in-python-code-to-braces
MSAA Role=F
```

Comment: Impressive - 6000 rep and using a screen reader. My hat off to you Sir!

Comment: I thought screen readers could read title attributes as well as alt attributes. The title attribute should include the Accepted On date.

Comment: Jaws reads the alt attribute by default although you can set it to read the title attribute instead.

Comment: @Marc - I also suggested this topic to be discussed in the next podcast. It is quite an important one IMHO. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14303/podcast-66-discussion-ideas-unofficial/18105#18105

Answer (score 8):

Accessibility is always a priority, and it is unfortunately often very hard for most devs (myself included) to fully understand what will work well, and what won't - or indeed some of the subtle silly things that we *should* get right but forget ("alt" text, etc).

I would suggest that you log *any* difficulties / suggestions on meta. Especially since they want to make a saleable product, they need to fix this ;-p

Answer (score 6):

It should probably say **Accepted**, if the question has been accepted, and **Click to Accept** otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

Any way to improve the accessibility for our visually impaired users is always a plus.

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed for a while now, so marking [status-completed].

Note that accepted answer checkbox image tags now look like this:

```
<img src="http://sstatic.net/mso/img/vote-accepted-on.png"
     class="vote-accepted"
     style="cursor:default"
     width="30"
     height="31"
     alt="check"
     title="The question owner accepted this as the best answer Nov 30 at 0:11">
```

Comment: Until you broke it with CSS sprites!