# Podcast #67 - Discussion Ideas. (Unofficial)

Tags: discussion, podcast

First. We had a pretty awesome thread for [Podcast #66 Discussion Ideas.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14303/podcast-66-discussion-ideas-unofficial) So please check that one out.

---

What would you like to see discussed on Podcast #67?

Please post only one topic per user and look down the list and vote up things you'd like to see. You can be as detailed as you wish.

---

Here are some of the highly voted ones from last time that still apply for #67.

> How about an interview with the FogCreek dev working on StackExchange. - [Nathan Koop](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14303/podcast-66-discussion-ideas-unofficial/16915#16915)
>
> I would like to hear how Jeff (and his team) Get Things Done! - [Decio Lira](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14303/podcast-66-discussion-ideas-unofficial/14547#14547)
>
> Since you rag on PHP every week, why not invite a PHP enthusiast - [jakemcgraw](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14303/podcast-66-discussion-ideas-unofficial/17307#17307)
>
> Interview David Smalley and/or Paul Farnell from doctype - [Jonathan Sampson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14303/podcast-66-discussion-ideas-unofficial/14319#14319)

---

[Podcast #67](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/podcast-67/)   [Transcript wiki](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W29079)

[<= previous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14303/podcast-66-discussion-ideas-unofficial)

Answer (score 12):

> **First Suggested**
>   [Podcast #66](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14303/podcast-66-discussion-ideas-unofficial/18105#18105)

After reading [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18097/non-visual-way-to-see-if-a-question-you-asked-has-an-accepted-answer) post and realising that we actually have a <kbd>blind-programmer</kbd> tag and two [confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370976/what-are-some-good-computer-science-resources-for-a-blind-programmer) blind users on StackOverflow, one with [6000+](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14744/jared) reputation already, I would like to know how and what has been done to make the site more accessible for these users, and although a minority how Jeff and Joel feel about reaching such a unique target?

I would also like to hear their input on the [What are some good computer science resources for a Blind Programmer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370976/what-are-some-good-computer-science-resources-for-a-blind-programmer) (Question 370976) question on StackOverflow.

Comment: I like this one. Could be extremely informative, in an oft-ignored area of UI design.

Comment: Be assured. We have a lot more than two blind programmers. OHHHH you mean visually blind. Nevermind.

Comment: StackExchange will support braille.

Comment: I'm upvoting as this is a great subject, but I'm wondering if it will ultimately be accepted over its "too localized" nature. On a personal note, I used to consider myself a talented developer - that is until I spoke with a blind user :) Working with the visually-impaired will really test your skills in developing good websites.

Comment: I will keep posting it until they do or Jeff tells me to stop. Hell might freeze over first thought.

Comment: @wood hates blind people and people who don't speak English as their primary language, so I doubt it.

Comment: I'd like to hear something about this even if it's tough luck the site mostly works for you so were not going out of our way to get the additional 10% of functionality to work.

Answer (score 6):

How about an interview with the FogCreek dev working on StackExchange

See full answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14303/podcast-66-discussion-ideas-unofficial/16915#16915)

Comment: It's a good answer and I linked to it in the question.

Comment: @olafur: Doesn't that kind of defeat the idea of voting?

Comment: +1 First *actual* answer, and a good one at that.

Comment: @Rich B it already has a lot of votes on the other thread.

Comment: @Olafur: I stand by my assertion that this ruins the idea of voting.

Comment: You can vote on the other item and this one as well then :)

Comment: @Olafur: Why not just post those answers in this thread? That is what would make sense.

Answer (score 3):

There should be a large boxing match between the people who keep fighting each other on MSO with Jeff and Joel as announcers.

Comment: Bareknuckle?

Answer (score 1):

Waffle-eating contest between Jeff and Joel. Winner gets to apologize for nauseating all listeners by furiously chewing on-air.

Comment: Jeff would win, but Joel would explode. As long as Joel somehow dies from it, I think it is win-win.

Comment: They should interview Marc G and ask him why he hates Waffles so much and see if he admits to the brainwashing the pancake industry has put him through.

Answer (score 0):

An official abdication by Jeff of his title as "King of Meta"

Comment: *facepalm* @ lack of humor detector.

Answer (score 0):

I've enjoyed most of the guests so far, and while I like the independent theme I would like to see an interview with programmer or sys admin from one of the vast masses of non-tech companies.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to [my other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19915/podcast-67-discussion-ideas-unofficial/20088#20088) ... I am more than willing to offer my services. :)

I am a computer programmer for the county hospital, with the intriguing twist that while I single-handedly run a server and website (running the home-grown education system) used by 5k users daily - I work in the education department not in the IT department.

I also have public speaking experience and a lovely baritone, so it shouldn't be that bad. Too bad the voice-over I did for our online orientation has been taken down... we needed to do some updates and the VPs didn't want to wait for a re-record.